# Select data for a date range

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a report in Webi report in BO 4.1. Is there a way to run a webi report to select data from a range of dates without prompt?  What I mean is: if I want to see sales for past 5 days from today, can I modify a report so that every time I run the report, it will fetch sales data for 5 prior dates from today? I have date field in the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like a `SELECT-OPTIONS` without a selection screen, then you can use `RANGES`:

```
data: r_date type range of vbka-erdat,  "range table
      wa_date like line of r_date.     "work area for range table

wa_date-sign   = 'I'.   "I = include, E = exclude
wa_date-option = 'BT'.  "EQ, BT, NE ....
wa_date-low    = sy-datum.
wa_date-high   = sy-datum - 5.
append wa_date to r_date.
```

An older syntax would be:

```
ranges r_date for vbka-erdat.  "range table

r_date-sign   = 'I'.   "I = include, E = exclude
r_date-option = 'BT'.  "EQ, BT, NE ....
r_date-low    = sy-datum.
r_date-high   = sy-datum - 5.
append r_date.
```

Comment: Hi Knut, I am sorry but the question is for a Webi report (SAP BO 4.1).  I don't think I can apply above script in webi.